# Python output entire column

Tags: python

Using python 2.4 i have a .txt file sorted into 3 colums, 9 spaces between each column which is the reason for x.split - roughly 1000 lines ex:

```
$1$sda4356:[sgb1_diska5.ldlbat44.libabl]talild_0329_base.rpt                                talild_0329_base.rpt                                                                      00000000000000005062
```

I'm using the following code to sort by column 3 (which is file size)

```
fobj = open('data.txt')
data = [ x.split() for x in fobj ]
fobj.close()

from operator import itemgetter
data.sort(key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
```

I want to print the output of an entire column and if possible with Python 2.4 even name them. If i do something like data[1] it will just output line 2 how can i get this to show column 2 instead. If i can't name it i see a few things with import csv but i can't figure out the right command to use the data i've already sorted instead of calling up the .txt file again.  Most are looking for file name as shown below

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
```

Comment: You need [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid - he needs more recent version of Python, Pandas depends on Python2.5.

Comment: Have you tried creating a different list for each column and just printing the list values for the desired column?  Btw, `with open()` is only supported in Python 2.5 and later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def getcolumn(n,data): 
    return (i[n] for i in data) # if this dosent work replace () with []

for i in getcolumn(1,data):
    print i
```